# Using Python requests module to Login a page but there have random generate code in login POST form

Tags: python, authentication, httprequest, python-requests

I got a problem to using request module in python to login to this website

```
import requests

s = requests.session()
login_data = {'username': 'XXXXXX', 'password': 'XXXXX', 'lt':'LT-806773-    6gJdPCbhwJ2RybNqwpeoW6msRNBZVj','execution':'e1s1','_eventId':'submit',}

s.post('https://access.ust.hk/cas/login', login_data)

r = s.get('https://access.ust.hk/cas/login')
print r.text
```

And the HTML is look like that, note that there have three para ramdom generate  each time I refreash the page: they are

> It

and

> execution

. how can I get those para to put in to my post script? please help

```
<div class="inputbox">
                 <form id="fm1" class="fm-v clearfix" action="/cas/login" method="post">

                  <div class="inputRow">
                      <label for="username" class="login_text mobileHidden"><span class="accesskey">U</span>sername</label>
                      <input id="username" name="username" class="required" tabindex="1" accesskey="u" size="25" autocomplete="false" type="text" placeholder="Username">
                  </div>

                  <div class="inputRow">
                      <label for="password" class="login_text mobileHidden"><span class="accesskey">P</span>assword</label>                     
                      <input id="password" name="password" class="required" tabindex="2" accesskey="p" value="" size="25" autocomplete="off" type="password" placeholder="Password">
                  </div>

                  <div class="inputRow">
                    <div class="rememberMe desktopHidden" id="rememberMeTagId">
                       <input name="rememberMe" id="rememberMe" value="true" tabindex="3" type="checkbox">
                       <label for="rememberMe" class="login_text"><span></span>Remember Me</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="loginBtn">
                     <input type="hidden" name="lt" value="LT-807439-pGK44uO34Dr3Mj4hCIuhemNlRGiwk0">
                     <input type="hidden" name="execution" value="e10s1">
                     <input type="hidden" name="_eventId" value="submit">
                     <input accesskey="l" class="button" tabindex="4" value="LOGIN" type="submit">
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="inputRow desktopHidden">
                        <a class="forget_pw_text" href="https://access.ust.hk/pw/" target="null">Forget / Change your password</a>
                  </div>
                 </form>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make a get request and parse the xml, using a library like BeautifulSoup, to get the generated tokens, and then include them in your POST request to login

Comment: but the link is radom  generated each time . how can i using the same link to post the request?

Comment: @Jackiewu each time you want to login, you would first have to make a get request to retrieve the generated link, then make the post request with that link

Comment: Got it ,so I first using get request to get the gen link and text ,then using regex to get those random parameter ,and make a post request to the link. It the workflow right ?:)